# Overlay a smaller rectangle on a UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage

I want to overlay a rectangle within an image. This code below currently works but it returns a rect with a thin frame. I cant change the rect frame width. One way to return a custom rect with thicker border is by using UIView but it's not possible to add a SubView to an UIImage. Any solution to this? Thank you.

-(UIImage *)drawRectangleOnImage:(UIImage *)img rect:(CGRect )rect{

```
CGSize imgSize = img.size;
CGFloat scale = 0;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgSize, NO, scale);
[img drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
[[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
UIRectFrame(rect);
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
```

}

Comment: "it's not possible to add a SubView to an UIImage" is not true. The interface builder won't let you do that, but there's no problem adding a subview to `UIImage` in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UIRectFrame](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623926-uirectframe) draws a frame around the inside of the specified rect. If you want to fill the area instead, you can use [UIRectFill](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623932-uirectfill).

To change the stroke and/or fill colour, you can call `-setStroke` or `-setFill` on `UIColor`. For example:

```
[[UIColor red] setFill];
UIRectFill(rect);
```

To set the stroke line width, you need to set the line width on the current CGContext:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10);
```

Edit:
There’s an even easier way: NSFrameRectWithWidth allows you to directly specify the width instead of setting the line width on the context.

Comment: No, I don't want a filled rectangle. I need just the frame.

Comment: I updated the answer to contain details on how to retrieve the current CGContext and change the line width.

Comment: @LorKamHoi sorry, had another look and there’s an even easier way. Added it to my answer.